# Jackson Mapping Infinite Recursion. Spring Data Rest

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-rest

My project setup is Spring Boot 1.3.1.RELEASE, Spring Data Rest.

I have an entity as follows

```
@Entity
public class Criteria extends BaseEntity {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "CRITERIA__GROUP", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CRITERIA__ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP__ID"))
    private Set<Group> planningCriteriaGroup = new HashSet<Group>();
}

@Entity
public class Group extends BaseEntity {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP__ID")
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>(0);
}

@Entity
public class Category extends BaseEntity {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Category parent;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Category> children = new HashSet<Category>(0);
}
```

When i curl to get criterias as

```
curl -v -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:8080/criterias"
```

The following error is thrown -

{"timestamp":1452510716889,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException","message":"Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources[\"_embedded\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources[\"_embedded\"])","path":"/criterias"}

**@JsonBackReference and @JsonManagedReference doesn't seem to solve the issue of infinite recursion.**

Comment: Just to sort out the obvious: are you sure you have Jackson configured to consider annotations on fields? If so, could you come up with a sample project showing that error and file a ticket in our [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST).

Comment: I tried adding this @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE) Still no success.

Answer (score 0):

you can use @JsonIgnore at parent.

Comment: No, this **REMOVE** the childs